# Probabilistic model of parallel web servers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling, queueing-theory

*Note:* The following probabilistic model of parallel web servers is abstracted from an engineering project. I am not good at probability theory and I am seeking some evaluations and suggestions.

> - Is the probabilistic model well-defined mathematically?
> - Are the three problems on the model reasonable?
> - Are they "solvable" (or quite difficult to solve), especially under the assumptions of the random variables in the model? If not, what is your suggestion?
> - Any references to similar problems are also appreciated.

*Probabilistic model:*

Consider $n$ web servers $S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_n$, each of which (denoted $S_i$) is responsible to process an individual stream (denoted $s_i$) of read/write requests.

1. All servers come into work simultaneously and they operate independently and parallelly.
2. Stream $s_1$ for server $S_1$ consists only of write requests. All other streams consist only of read requests.
3. The processing time $t$ of each request (either read or write) is modeled as independently, [exponentially distributed variables [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), with a rate $\lambda_1$.
4. The request arrival process for each stream is modeled as independently, [homogeneous Poisson process [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process#Homogeneous), with a rate $\lambda_2$.

Some notations: For each request $q$, we denote its start time, finish time, processing interval by $q_{.st}$, $q_{.ft}$, and $[q_{.st}, q_{.ft}]$, respectively.

*Problems:*

> (1). For a read request $r$, what is the probability that it starts during the processing interval of some write request (denoted $w$) (i.e., $r_{.st} \in [w_{.st}, w_{.ft}]$)?

Note that if $w$ exists, it is unique (for there is a total order of all the write requests).

> (2). For a read request $r$, the set of read requests that finished before $r$ started is denoted by $r^{\prec} = \{\text{read request } r': r'_{.ft} \le r_{.st} \}$.
>   When (1) happens, what is probability that there exists some read request $r' \in r^{\prec}$ which overlaps $w$?

Note that we already have $r'_{.ft} \le r_{.st}$ and $r_{.st} \in [w_{.st}, w_{.ft}]$, so it is sufficient to check whether $r'_{.ft} \ge w_{.st}$ is satisfied, as shown in the following figure.

[image: overlapping]

> (3). As an extension to (2), what is the probability that there are exactly $m$ read requests in $r^{\prec}$ of which each overlaps $w$?

Comment: I believe, the answer to the two problems will depend upon the service discipline (First Come First Served, Processor Sharing, Priority,...). Can you specify the discipline?

Comment: It is "First Come First Served". No priority here. However, what does the term "Processor Sharing" mean? In this model, each server handles with an individual stream of quests. Does this mean that it is not "Processor Sharing"? I am trying to learn more about related theories such as queueing theory and to make the problem more clear. Thanks.

Comment: @user137846 I forgot to notify you in my last comment. Sorry for that.

Comment: Processor sharing means that all the tasks present in the queue share the capacity of the processor equally. You can think of this as multi-tasking in computers. Each task runs in parallel on the same processor. There is a vast literature on scheduling in queues. Some of the ideas are explained in Part VII of the this book http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~harchol/PerformanceModeling/book.html

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party and making a few extra assumptions, but what you want is [Little's Law and related formulas](http://web.mst.edu/~gosavia/queuing_formulas.pdf). Think of the activity on $S_i$ as a queuing process.

1. Probability of read request during write request on $S_1$:

$$= P(\text{$S_1$ is not idle})$$

$S_1$ can be modeled an $M/M/1$ Queue. For an $M/M/1$ Queue, Probability of idleness is $\rho$.

$$\rho =\frac{\lambda}{\mu} = \frac{\text{arrival rate}}{\text{service rate}} = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}$$.

Intuitively, if requests arrive faster than you can serve them, your system will never be idle due to back up.

2. It sounds like you want to know the probability that more than one arrival interrupts the same write request.

This is the probability that there is $> 1$ person in the system. For read requests, we can model this as an $M/M/(n-1)$ queuing system. Thus, we're interested in the statistic $ 1 - P_0$ where $P_0$ is the probability that there are $0$ read requests in the system when request $r$ arrives.

$$P_0 = 1 / [\sum_{m=0}^{n - 2}\frac{((n-1)\rho)^m}{m!} + \frac{((n-1)\rho)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!(1-\rho)}]$$

where

$$\rho = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1*(n-1)}$$

3. See M/M/c [queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/c_queue) for references.

$$P_k = 
\begin{cases}
P_0\frac{((n-1)\rho)^k}{k!},\text{ $k < n-1$} \\
P_0\frac{(n-1)^{n-1}\rho^k}{(n-1)!},\text{ $o.w.$}
\end{cases}$$

$$$$
Disclaimer: All solutions are steady state, limiting approximations.

$$$$
$$$$
Aside: the notation is very hard to follow. A less kind person may call it painful. Try framing it a little more simply. No need to over complicate.